# How to use Swagger API with Bearer Auth in R

Tags: r, authentication, swagger

What is the syntax to use the Swagger API in R with the Bearer Auth?
(this is a question relating to the Cherwell API)

Answer (score 1):

Prep: you will need a user id, password for the swagger server...
Then you'll need your public token
Then you'll need to generate the Bearer token...
I used swagger to do this via the browser tool.
Then this should set you right once you've replaced the 'xxx's with your prementioned creds.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
usr = 'xxx'
pwd = 'xxx'
tkn = 'xxxx'
qry <- paste0("https://xxx/xxx/api/V1/getteams?api_key=",tkn)
bearer <- "Bearer xxx"

res <- GET(qry,
           authenticate(usr,pwd),
           add_headers(Authorization = bearer)
           )
                       
content(res)
```